# How to apply an action on each alive member on screen belonging to a particular group?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a group containing 20 members. For every 2 seconds, 10 members are drawn on screen randomly and they move with a certain velocity. When a player overlaps with them I am calling this function on each group member:

```js
coing.forEach(function (item) {
    coins.body.velocity.x = 0;
}, this);
```

All the members which are infront of the player (they are approaching the player) are stopping but the members which got past the player are continuing to move. I want each and every member on screen to stop but I'm unable to achieve it.

Comment: Is `coing` a typo or intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing your code myself, it seems like you are not setting the velocity of each item, but on the entire `coins` array. You should probably do something like:

```js
coins.forEach(function (item) {
    item.body.velocity.x = 0;
}, this);
```

Again, this is just something I noticed, without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry markus, i added `coins.body.velocity.x=0` instead of `item.body.velocity.x=0` now my problem is solved :) , i thought `item` is group member.